# Using python to find repeated names in a txt file

Tags: python, duplicates, compare

I want to use python ( although any language is fine ), to look through a structured text file which looks like this:

```
========= Weekend of 2016-12-02: ================
Schedule1:
bob@email
Schedule2:
john@email
bob@email
Schedule3:
Terry@email
========= Weekend of 2016-12-09: ================
Schedule1:
jake@email
Schedule2:
mike@email
bob@email
Schedule3:
howard@email
```

This pattern repeats for the remainder of the year, what I am trying to accomplish is to find any overlapping schedules. So if bob@email is on more than one schedule for that weekend I would like to find and print that.
Example:

```
Overlaps found for:
========= Weekend of 2016-12-02: ================
bob@email is scheduled for schedule1, and schedule2.
```

Since this is the only overlap, this is the only occurrence that would print, if there were more then they would print in the same format underneath each other .
Is there any way to accomplish this?

The code I've found so far allows me to find each weekend and print that, however I'm not sure how to look at the contents in more detail.

```
import re
    def compare():
         with open("weekends.txt","r") as fp:
             for result in re.findall('Weekend of (.*?):', fp.read(), re.S):
                 print(result)
```

This yields

```
2016-12-02
2016-12-09
```

Thank you, and please let me know if there are any questions.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Right I apologize, the reason I did not include any code is because what I've written have only been simple for loops with sets, I'm very much a beginner so my code was rather useless.

Comment: We don't judge people on their ability to code, we judge people on how much effort they put in. The most you put in, even if it's a simple `print` function, it shows that you have tried something and hopefully tried to research something.

Comment: Right, I've added the code that seems to do the most for me, which essentially separates it into blocks of weekends, I feel this is a first step, however I may be approaching this in a completely improper way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this with a regex creating a dict of sets:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

data={}

with open(fn) as f_in:
    txt=f_in.read()

for block in re.finditer(r'^=+\s+([^:]+:)\s=+\s+([^=]+)', txt, re.M):
    di={}
    for sc in re.finditer(r'^(Schedule\s*\d+):\s*([\s\S]+?)(?=(?:^Schedule\s*\d+)|\Z)', block.group(2), re.M):
        di[sc.group(1)]=set(sc.group(2).splitlines())
    data[block.group(1)]=di

for date, DofS in data.items():
    c=Counter()
    for s in DofS.values():
        c+=Counter(s)
    inverted={k:[] for k, v in c.items() if v>1} 
    if not inverted:
        continue
    print date  
    for k in DofS:
        for e in DofS[k]:
            if e in inverted:
                inverted[e].append(k)    
    print "\t",inverted
```

Prints:

```
Weekend of 2016-12-02:
    {'bob@email': ['Schedule1', 'Schedule2']}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a map to store `<name, list of schedule>`, like `<bob@email, [Schedule1]>`, when you go through each weekend. Everytime, you want to add a new item, you can check whether the key has been set already. If yes, add that schedule to that corresponding list. If no, add a new item to that map. Then, when you print out, only print the item with more than 1 schedule in the list.

For Python, you can use dictionary as the map.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm